# Error building ELLCC

Tags: macos, clang, cross-compiling, binutils, ellcc

Running the `build` script from ELLCC results in this error

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/binutils/binutils  -I. -I../../../src/binutils/binutils -I../bfd -I../../../src/binutils/binutils/../bfd -I../../../src/binutils/binutils/../include -I./../intl -DLOCALEDIR="\"/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ellcc--svn-HEAD/lib/share/locale\"" -Dbin_dummy_emulation=bin_vanilla_emulation  -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Werror -Wno-unused-value -Wno-shadow  -MT nm.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/nm.Tpo -c -o nm.o ../../../src/binutils/binutils/nm.c
../../../src/binutils/binutils/nm.c:1690:28: error: 'sbrk' is deprecated
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      char *lim = (char *) sbrk (0);
                           ^
/usr/include/unistd.h:582:7: note: 'sbrk' declared here
void    *sbrk(int);
         ^
```

The following compilers have been used with the same result:

- gcc 4.8
- llvm-gcc 2.8
- llvm 3.3

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue compiling binutils-2.24 on Mac OSX Mavericks 13.2.0 with clang.  Thanks to Richard Pennington's suggestion, I was able to get binutils to compile by specifying a few other `-Wno-error` arguments to gcc by setting `CFLAGS` before running `configure`.  Namely, these are the commands I ran to build and install binutils:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-function" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/toolchain-arm-linux-elf --target=arm-linux-elf
make
make install
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the binutils configure script accepts an `--disable-werror` argument, which disables gcc turning warnings into errors, and removes the need for the settings `CFLAGS`.  With this argument, building could be done as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/toolchain-arm-linux-elf --target=arm-linux-elf --disable-werror
make
make install
```

Comment: binutils 2.25 might not have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because sbrk() is deprecated on OSX, -Werror is enabled for the binutils build, and the compiler (in this case "gcc" is an alias for clang) rightly complains about the use of sbrk(). I'll be looking into eliminating this error this weekend when I won't have to be at my day job. ;-)

I looked into it a bit more. This happened because the latest version of OS X (Mavericks) uses clang as its compiler and /usr/include/unistd.h has a deprecated declaration of sbrk().

The solution was to add a -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations option to the CFLAGS for binutils. I also had to make a few other changes to complete the Max OS build. You can find the latest stuff in the [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) subversion tree.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Perhaps the `Makefile` needs a clean/distclean target? Having pulled the latest ELLCC update, running build results in https://gist.github.com/7889240